# What programs, websites or other applications leverage Mt Gox's API?

Tags: mtgox, api, trade

I'm looking for sample programs and apps that leverage Mt Gox and learning what they do. Is there such a list in existence?

Links to the appropriate BitcoinTalk or Wiki page would be more than sufficient as long as it's centralized.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of any official list but here are a few that I've found

**Github Repos**

- [bitfloor books](https://github.com/bitfloor/trader.nodejs)
- [bitcoin-arbitrage](https://github.com/maxme/bitcoin-arbitrage)
- [metabit](https://github.com/mtmiron/metabit)
- [mtgox-node.js-client](https://github.com/programmarchy/node-mtgox-websocket-client)

**Websites**

- [bitcoin charts](http://bitcoincharts.com/)
- [bitinstant](https://www.bitinstant.com/)

Comment: A good answer but nothing that a simple google search wouldn't find.

Comment: @Chris feel free to add to it

Answer (score 1):

There's a Python script that generates a database of all Mt. Gox transactions ever, along with a pre-scraped database of all transactions, here: http://cahier2.ww7.be/bitcoinmirror/phantomcircuit/